# How to split the rows of a dataset depending on certain conditions?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, boolean

I want to be able to compare per user the scores of first and last row (there are only two rows per user) of the dataset and see if the score increases or decreases between the sessions.

I have a dataset looking like this:

```
User    Session   Score
1       1         4
        2         5
2       1         5
        2         3
3       1         4
        2         5
4       1         3
        2         3
```

I have no idea how to call upon an index with a specific condition.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach using [`df.groupby().nth()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.nth.html) and [`df.agg()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.agg.html)

```py
first_last = df.groupby('User').nth([0, -1])
diff = first_last.groupby('User')['Score'].agg(lambda x: x.iloc[-1] - x.iloc[0])
print(diff)
```

---

```
User
1    1
2   -2
3    1
4    0
Name: Score, dtype: int64
```